# Auto-schedule solutions using Excel or Python solver

Tags: python, excel, solver

In a certain Week, specific Units (W, U, and S) are available to visit on specific dates. Unit W is available for the whole working week (Monday - Friday), Unit U is only available on Monday and Tuesday and unit S is only available on Tuesday and Friday.

Constraints:

Each visitation date (the day of the week) mustn't clash with another date.

Is this possible to solve via Excel or Python solver?